# Why is my click function not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've created a simple js project which plots a series of points using leaflet.js.

I then want to populate an info window with point specific data with an on click event. But I can't seem to get it to work.

This is roughly what I've done:

```
var circle = L.circle(
    [data[i]['latitude'], data[i]['longitude']],
    50,
    { color: 'red', fillColor: 'red', fillOpacity: .5}
).addTo(map)
.bindPopup(data[i]['SCHNAME'])
.on('click', fill_info_window(data, i));

function fill_info_window(data, i){ /* fill data */ }
```

Unfortunately, it automatically fills the window with the latest data.

Why isn't it working?

You can see the project here:

http://www.thisisstaffordshire.co.uk/images/localpeople/ugc-images/275796/binaries/leaguetableTemplate.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this line:

```
.on('click', fill_info_window(data, i));
```

...you're **calling** the `fill_info_window` function, not just referring to it. You want to do something like this:

```
.on('click', function() {
    fill_info_window(data, i);
});
```

unless you're in a loop (that `i` variable makes me think maybe you are). If you are, then:

```
.on('click', makeHandler(data, i));
```

...where `makeHandler` looks like this:

```
function makeHandler(theData, index) {
    return function() {
        fill_info_window(theData, index);
    };
}
```

The reason you don't want my first answer in a loop is that all of the handlers will refer to the same `data` and `i` variables, and see their value as of when the handler is *called*, not when it's registered. That's why we use the `makeHandler` function instead, so it creates a closure over something that doesn't change. More on my blog: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Comment: Thank you, sir, that's absolutely brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to bind the *function* as a handler, not its result from calling it. So remove the invocation and use `….on('click', fill_info_window);`. See also [this quirksmode article about event handling](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html#link2): *No parenthesis!*.

Comment: I don't know what the correct args are - I neither have experience with leaflet nor do I know what `fill_info_window` does.

Comment: You think that's what he wants? I guessed he just copy-pasted the function signature.