# Why must callbacks in jQuery be anonomous?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-callback

This works just as expected but I don't like it.

```
$('#login-form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  init.login();
});

var init = {
  login: function() {
  // do login stuff
  }
};
```

This is what I want but it does not work.

```
$('#login-form').on('submit', init.login(event));

var init = {
  login: function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // do login stuff
  }
};
```

Why?

Comment: What error does it give? I think you can pass the function but you are doing it the wrong way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my click function not working as expected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857225/why-is-my-click-function-not-working-as-expected) and many others

Comment: @Bergi Could be. I read it but did not get it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will work, you're calling the function (the value given as a callback will be the result of the function) rather than passing it as a value

```
$('#login-form').on('submit', init.login);
```

Comment: +1, but the other thing to note is that if inside `init.login`, you were to use `this` to reference other properties of `init`, then you would need to add a `bind` call as well: `$('#login-form').on('submit', init.login.bind(init));`

Comment: Thanks! I think I get it. I got "calling a function" and "displaying the result of the function" mixed up. But how do I keep the event object? I need to do preventDefault on it? Is there a third parimeter (bool set to false) I can use? or does that return false instead?

Comment: No problem, the event object will get passed to any function you provide, so it will still get passed to your login function

Answer (score 5):

`init.login(event)` *calls* the function `init.login`, passing the (non-existent) variable `event` to it. If you want to pass the function itself as callback, don't call it:

```
$('#login-form').on('submit', init.login);
```

You will have to declare that function before you pass it though, at this point `init.login` is `undefined`.

Comment: So the event object is only available in the anonymous function?

Comment: When `.on` is calling the callback, it passes it a parameter. `.on` is defined like this: `function on(event, callback) { ... callback('foo'); ... }`. It's getting your callback as argument, then it's calling your callback, passing it a parameter. Your callback receives this value in a parameter it calls `event`. You can call this parameter anything you want. And yes, it's obviously only available inside the callback when `.on` calls it.

Comment: Thank you for the details. Kinda tricky. Gotta read up on this.

Answer (score 4):

You're already calling the function in that line (with `undefined`, there is no `event` yet). You need to pass the function itself (not its result):

```
$('#login-form').on('submit', init.login);
```

Notice that `init.login` is still an anonymous function, it has no name :-) Also beware that the method is called with `this` being the login form element, not the `init` object. If you needed that, you'd use `.on('submit', init.login.bind(init))`.

Comment: So how do I access the event object?

Comment: @KarlPokus: It should be the parameter of the `init.login` function, i.e. `{
  login: function(event) {
  /* do login stuff */
  }
}`